# How to create an user plug-in in Xpages?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to create an OSGi Plug-in to extend XPages but unsure of where to start.

Can anyone show me easy way to create a sample plugin?

Where do i have to write my java code and how do I add it to an updatesite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tutorial will walk you through creating a plugin, how to build and deploy it.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_XPages_Library

There is also a blank XPage plugin available at the link below (although it is part of the overall tutorial).

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Blank_XPages_Library

(Overall tutorial is here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Master_Table_of_Contents_for_XPages_Extensibility_APIs_Developer_Guide )

Answer (score 4):

I would also suggest looking at the XSP Starter library available on OpenNTF by Nathan Freeman. This library, once imported into Eclipse, will provide you with the base of your new Extension Library already written, then you just need to use some of the examples given in the other answer to complete the java code that you want to provide as part of your new library.

Comment: Declan - if I download the XSP Starer Library its just a JAR file.  IS this right?